# WSO2 Governance Registry upgrade?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

WSO2 has some great documentation about upgrading between versions, but we have version 4.5.3, and I don't see in the documents if I can upgrade directly from 4.5.3 to 5.1.0?

Their docs go between levels, like 4.5.3 to 4.6, 4.6 to 5.0, 5.0 to 5.1.

Is there a process to go directly from 4.5.3 to 5.1 (without having to do the interim levels)?

Answer (score 0):

No, We provide steps for migrating to next version from current version. You have to migrate step by step. Or you can combine the steps and migrate.

Providing migration scripts for two not consequent version isn't scalable. Image how many combination of script we have to maintain.

Comment: Are the versions that drastically different that I couldn't, say, SKIP going to 4.6 but go directly to 5.0 from 4.5.3?    I'd rather NOT have to do three separate upgrades to the system -- VERY time/resource consuming to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't migrate directly from 4.5.3 to 5.1.0, you have to do incremental migration. Other than that recently we released the new G-Reg 5.2.0 which is a much more improved version of 5.1.0, therefore we prefer you to use the latest version possible.

We have tested these migrations scripts in our local environments and it won't take that much time to migrate. lets say you have 500 artifacts in G-Reg 4.5.3 and it will take less than 2 days to do the migrations till G-Reg 5.2.0. By looking at the benefits your getting after the migration I think the time/resource consumed will worth a lot.

Please find the official documentation for [Upgrading from a Previous Release](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release). Please download the all new [G-Reg 5.2.0 from here](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/).

Comment: TY -- I appreciate it.  I have customizations that I've added to the system as well, so it will take much longer than 2 days due to the effort to make sure all the customizations work for each version.   I DO appreciate the answer though, and the general timing for doing the upgrade.

Comment: If you can tell me what are the customizations, i can tell you what are the version that you can skip testing.